# Function for two strings in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-defined-functions, xlsxwriter

I want to create a user defined function in that has two parameters. 
what I have tried that doesn't work is this:

```
def make_var_columns (wksheet, element):
    + wksheet +.write_row('B6', Iris[''+ element +'cm'])
```

Which I would want to be called later by this:

`make_var_columns("worksheet1", "Sepal_length")`

and

```
make_var_columns("worksheet2", "Petal_width")
```

If these were not done using functions I successfully use this:

`worksheet1.write_row('B6', Iris['Sepal_lengthcm'])`

and

`worksheet2.write_row('B6', Iris['Petal_widthcm'])`

Comment: Try `def make_var_columns(wksheet, element): return wb.get_worksheet_by_name(wksheet).write_row('B6', Iris["{}cm".format(element)])`; where `wb` is the `Workbook` object created from `xlsxwriter.Workbook(workbook_name)`.

Comment: It might be simpler to pass the worksheet object rather than the name of the worksheet. If you can't do that and have to pass the sheet name then use `get_worksheet_by_name()` as suggested by @Abdou.

Answer (score 0):

get_worksheet_by_name is deprecated, so you can use wb[WORKSHEET_NAME_HERE]

```
def make_var_columns(wksheet, element): 
    return wb[wksheet].write_row('B6', Iris["{}cm".format(element)])
```

Comment: as a better practice, pass `wb` as a parameter to the function instead of accessing the global variable.

Comment: Where does it say that `get_worksheet_by_name` is deprecated?

Comment: The `get_worksheet_by_name()` method is **not** deprecated.